# Remove Java Plugin messages from applet console

Tags: java, logging, applet

Java Plugin messages, on the different levels like "basic", "network", "security", etc., go to the output of the Java Console.

I'd like to hide this output (not the specific application output) from the console.
Especially network: since it prints a url I want to stay hidden.

Redirecting System.out and System.err doesn't work: these messages don't go through this channel.

Is there a way to hid these messages from the server - so there is no way the client can see these messages, even if setting the wordiest debug level?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do that.**

What the console shows by default is defined **by the user** using Java Control Panel, and you - as a programmer - cannot change or block those settings.

Besides - users should be able to know what your application does, why it communicates to remote servers, and what data it sends. Hiding the fact, that you send some data to your servers may lead your application to be considered harmful and spyware. And unless you *actually are creating spyware*, you don't want that.